# How do check if an item exists in a multimensional numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a array of numpy arrays

`[array([5, 5, 5]), array([6, 6, 6])]`

However if I try to check if an object exists in that array

`[5, 5, 5] in x`

I get this error

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Is there any way to fix this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: First let's be clear, is `x` a list or `ndarray`?  If `ndarray` how did you create it?  You get the ambiguity error because `in` is using an equality test, and `an_array==something` produces a boolean array, many true/false values.  `alist==another_list` produces a simple True/False.  That's not the case with arrays.  So in general `in` is a poor test when working with arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are check to see if a list exists in an array of arrays. Convert your list to an array and it should work.

```
>>> x=np.array([np.array([5, 5, 5]), np.array([6, 6, 6])])
>>> np.array([5, 5, 5]) in x
True
```